# Virtual Audio Device Python

Tags: python

I'm looking to create a program where I take an audio input stream, whether it be microphone or an audio file etc. Perform some arbitrary processing to it and then output this signal to a virtual microphone.

The part I'm struggling with is the outputting to a virtual microphone because i haven't found a way to create one in Python. I know there are third party applications to create virtual audio pipelines, but I would prefer to have it all in one program.

I am aware of Microsoft's Virtual Audio Device Technology, but I have absolutely no idea how to use it or where to start.

If someone is able to help me figure out how to create a virtual audio Device in Python, or how to use Microsoft's Virtual Audio Device Technology that would be fantastic.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide some more information regarding your use case? Do you absolutely have to create a virtual sound source or simply process audio in quasi-realtime and record the result of that operation?

Comment: I need for it to function as if it were just an audio filter or pass through, then streamed as an input to a microphone